# Unable to login to twitter using python requests library

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have tried to login to the twitter account using requests library. But I am getting url response as "400". It is not working. I used all the required payload parameters and headers. But still, I am unable to figure out how to login.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload={
"session[username_or_email]":"***************",
"session[password]":"*************",
"authenticity_token":"*************",
"ui_metrics":'{"rf":{"a4f2d7a8e3d9736f0815ae7b34692191bca9f114a7d5602c7758a3e6087b6b30":0,"ad92fc8b83fb5dec3f720f89a7f0fb415a26130516362f230b02251edd96a54a":0,"a011babb5c5df598f93bcc4a38dfad0276f69df36faff48eea95bac67cefeffe":0,"a75214752b7e90fd50725fce21cc26761ef3613173b0f8764d52c8b53f136bbf":0},"s":"mTArUSdNtTOm6WaGwNeRjMAU3EhNA3VGbFeCIZeEkjjLTAbccFDTJjcTEB2tQ9iuNJUzniFKyvhZNOGdH1LIwmi1YSMcFTOHu2Wi49yKvONv0obfg1dW27znR_C2n-ev2zMvN5166j1ccsxWKIheiWw-eHM7oXA54U40cWHvdCrunJJKj2INkTrcVph-y2fccu1m3hp31vngqBiL-XmeLWYiyZ-NYOmV8f5iXW9WWMvISTcSwzz9vd_n9-tLSKociT-1ap5ZVFWNUWIycSflj8WcOmmRFzq4kwa-NsS0FRp-DQ2FOkozhhhQi9HDvSODUlGsdQWBPkGKKtDWbtnj9gAAAWEty4Xv"}',
"scribe_log":"",
"redirect_after_login":"",
"authenticity_token":"******************",
"return_to_ssl":"",
"remember_me":"1",
"lang":""
}
headers={
"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control":"max-age=0",
"cookie":'moments_profile_moments_nav_tooltip_self=true; syndication_guest_id=v1%3A150345116906281638; eu_cn=1; kdt=QErLcBT9OjM5gjEznmsRcHlMTK6biDyAw4gfI5ro; remember_checked_on=1; _ga=GA1.2.1923324433.1496571570; tfw_exp=0; _gid=GA1.2.106381927.1516638134; __utma=43838368.1923324433.1496571570.1516764481.1516764481.1; __utmz=43838368.1516764481.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); lang=en; ct0=7ceea26f7fd3d186152512d26365cddf; _twitter_sess=BAh7CiIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCL8wyy1hAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlNjJjODQ1MjZiZWQzOGUyODZlOWUxNmNkMWJhZTZjYjc6B2lkIiU4MmZm%250AYWQ3Mzc1OGFhNmJjOTIxZjlmOGEyMzk3MjE1NToJdXNlcmwrCQAAVbhKiEIN--32d967262e1de8852d20ace15ec93d87b9a902a8; personalization_id="v1_snKt6bqCONQsnFuE8EOZDA=="; guest_id=v1%3A151689245583269291; _gat=1; ads_prefs="HBERAAA="; twid="u=955475925457502208"; auth_token=50decb38f16f3c264f480b0cd1cc30a9bcce9f08',
"referer":"https://twitter.com/login",
"upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
}
res = requests.get("https://twitter.com/login",data=payload,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
print(res.status_code)
print(res.url)
for item in soup.find_all(class_="title"):
    print(item.text)
```

How to login to twitter? what all parameters did i miss? Please help me out with this. 
**Note:** I am not using APIs or selenium driver. I want to do it using requests library. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The login url you are using in your request parameter should be `https://twitter.com/sessions`. Moreover, it should be a `post` request. However, how come you think that `data=payload` can be passed as parameter when you send a `get` request? Ain't that `params=payload`? Last of all: `"ui_metrics"` it should be passed as `json()` otherwise you may not be able to grab any data from that page.

Comment: how to pass ui_metrics as json?

Comment: Can you please modify the code and show here?

Comment: Go there to find the working solution: [Link_To_the_solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479115/getting-200-response-but-not-logging-in-using-python-requests-library). I've already tested that.

Comment: If you look at <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/48479671/10668202">this page</a>, you will find the answer.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the GET method to access an auth endpoint, usually the POST method is used for such purposes, try using `requests.post` instead of `requests.get`.